# connecting MySQL remotely

Tags: mysql

I am developing an application which, on providing the host, username, password and table name, connects to the database and shows the required table. Now i want it to connect remote databases(MySql) too. How can I make it remotely accessible? I am using Plesk panel. Or should I ring my hosting company and ask them to do this because in plesk panel, I can't find the command line for mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of hosting do you use?
For normal shared webhosting, this is in general not possible as the providers don't allow access from outside.

If you have your own server (either virtual or real one) this should be possible in general. You have to open port 3306 (standard mysql port) in your firewall and you have to ensure that the user you connect with has the right to access the database you want (host entry (in mysql/db table afair) must be set to "%" instead ot "localhost".)

Comment: Most Webhosting service providers not allows remote connecting due to security reason.Some of then restrict also local TCP connections and allows only socket/named pipes.